# My keyboard works fine but firefox won't let me type.

Tags: keyboard

Whenever I try to use firefox the cursor works but I can't type anything. I tried looking for anything on settings to help but I found nothing. I had to exit Ubuntu and use Windows to ask this question.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please give us more data on your system? Which version of Ubuntu you have, which firefox, etc, can help pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall iBus from the Ubuntu Software Center, and reboot.