# Ubuntu 20.04 systemd-coredump user ownership

Tags: permissions, 20.04, systemd, crash, ownership

My Ubuntu 20.04 kinda crashed. That is, in the middle of work mouse started jittering and and then froze completely. This has happened before (once per 10 days), it would usually come to senses, but now the only thing I could do is reboot the whole computer.

After reboot, all sorts of "permission denied" errors started popping out. It would seem that my home directory got owned by `systemd-coredump` user and `jovan` group (my user group). I attempted to regain ownership (`jovan:jovan`), but it only succeeded temporary - shortly after, home directory ownership was reverted to `systemd-coredump`

I am not really familiar with `systemd-coredump` as a utility. Does anyone know how to fix this?

### UPDATE

I have gone over the close proximity of the problem via `journald` in an attempt to find what went wrong. I spotted a lot of

`Memory pressure relief`

messages emitted from `gnome-shell`. Apart from that, `slack` and `Zoom` seems to have struggled to keep up. Within the logs, 10 minutes prior to crash, I saw this:

```
Aug 14 19:43:32 jovan-Z68X-UD5-B3 gnome-shell[2978]: 
JS ERROR: TypeError: themeNode is null
close@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/boxpointer.js:122:20
close@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/popupMenu.js:944:30
RenameFolderMenu/this._fileItemMappedId<@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano/desktopGrid.js:727:22
_updateVisibility@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/layout.js:941:9
showOverview@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/layout.js:323:14
show@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/overview.js:564:28
toggle@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/overview.js:688:18
_initializeUI/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:223:22
```

## UPDATE-2:

It seems that now, everything is back as it was. Even the toolbar theme is back (I set the smaller icon size, which became bigger after the crash).

File ownership seems alright, as well.

What I did:

- Uninstalled iBus Table Keyboard (suggested here [My keyboard works fine but firefox won't let me type.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/374624/my-keyboard-works-fine-but-firefox-wont-let-me-type)). Firefox did not let me type anything in the address bar
- Again `chown`-ed the whole HOME directory
- Rebooted

I hate these situations (when things fix "themselves"). Has anyone had scenario like this? I would like to learn from it and avoid it in future :)

Answer (score 2):

You can run docker as non-root. Just define a UID you like. If you run it as root it will use the coredump id.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got it.

So, after I did what I described in the question, I kept on doing my regular work. What I've found is that my `docker` container `mysql` crashed when I attempted to do `docker cp`. This reverted the ownership of the whole HOME directory, again, to `systemd-coredump`.

This time, I used `coredumpctl` to see what went wrong:

```
TIME                            PID   UID   GID SIG COREFILE  EXE
Fri 2020-08-14 20:40:57 CEST   2489  1000  1000   6 present   /opt/eset/esets/bin/esets_gui
Sat 2020-08-15 00:07:00 CEST   2014  1000  1000   6 present   /usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs
```

So, ESET GUI app crashed, but more importantly `tracker-miner-fs` also crashed. Found out I needed to remove:

- $HOME/.cache/tracker
- $HOME/.config/tracker (if exists)
- $HOME/.local/share/tracker

This way tracker would start from scratch and will not crash...

Comment: Not sure if this related but I'm busy chasing up a similar issue. On Ubuntu 18.04 and before the `docker` group had `gid 999` but in Ubuntu 20.04 that gid is now taken by `systemd-coredump`. The `docker` group now seems to default to gid 998. This creates incompatibilities when operating across different versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Docker Postgres images also [creates and set gid (amd uid) 999](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/db430ccd715678b60d7c7b9a0fee577991998837/14/bullseye/Dockerfile#L21)